# Can't convert drawable resource to file

Tags: android, file, drawable

```
I'm trying to convert file *logo_image.png* in `drawable/` folder to a `File`.
```

The following code fails as `f` is `null`;

```
int drawableResourceId = 
     context.getResources().getIdentifier("logo_image", 
                                          "drawable", 
                                           context.getPackageName());                 

File f=new File("logo_image"+".png");
try
{         
     InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) 
                                  context.getResources()
                                            .openRawResource(drawableResourceId);
     OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f);
     byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
     int len;
     while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0)
         out.write(buf,0,len);

     out.close();
     inputStream.close();
}
catch (IOException e){
}
```

Comment: what drawableResourceId do you get ?

Comment: @Luizje id of image logo_image.png

Comment: Ok so thats not 0. have you set the permissions in your manifest? ANd why dont you set the directory for the file? And should'nt you create the file first if it dont exists?

Comment: @Luizje which permissions in your manifest?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @Luizje I have added this:  if (!f.exists()) {f.mkdirs();}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49668/discussion-between-nick-unuchek-and-luizje)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 . Check if you have a set the permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

2 .Set a outdirectory for the output file

3 . check if file exists otherwise call f.createNewFile();